# Find all functions realizing equality

Tags: functions, inequality, summation

Let $f: \mathbb{Z}\to \mathbb{Z}$ be a (strictly) increasing function. Prove that

$$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} \left(\dfrac {1}{2|f(n)|+1} - \dfrac {1}{2(|f(n)|+f(n)-f(n-1))+1}\right) \leq \dfrac {4} {3}.$$

Find all functions realizing equality.

**Attempt**: I think I need the sum to reach its maximum when. Fill in the missing numbers in the function ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case $f(n) = n$. We get:

$$\sum_{n\in Z} \frac{2}{(2|n|+1)(2|n|+3)} = \frac{2}{3} + 2\sum_{n\in N} \frac{2}{(2|n|+1)(2|n|+3)} = \frac{4}{3}.$$

Since $f: Z \rightarrow Z$ and f is increasing the terms of the series are always positive, thus the series is convergent iff it is absolutely convergent. As such we can reorder terms without concerning ourselves with changing the limit. In the case $f(n) = n + K$ with a integer constant $K$, the sum is the same as for $f(n) = n$ only the term which used to occur in the position $N$ will occur at the position $N-K$ now. Reorder the series and we get that the series is convergent and the limit is equal to $\frac{4}{3}$.

So far all of these functions were ordered bijections of the integers. If you omit terms on a strictly increasing function from the integers to itself the strictly increasing nature of the function $f$ forces you to be strictly larger for all subsequent terms. To finish the proof you will use this to make a comparison argument between any strictly increasing function and an ordered bijection. Hopefully this reasoning is enough and I will leave as an exercise the final comparison.